# C# extracting value from string

Tags: c#, regex, string, extract

I'm trying to extract a value from a string. The string looks like this:

```
<iframe src="/test.php?aed=asd" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The only thing that changes in the link is the value after aed. What would be the easiest way to extract it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this properly you should be using an HTML parsing library, but for a simple extraction, you can use something like:

```
Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=/test\.php\?aed=)[^""&]+").Value
```

Means: after seeing the string "/test.php?aed=", match everything up to the next quote or ampersand.

Comment: That's awesome, works great. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as it's avaible.

Comment: `[^""&]` --- one double quote here is useless.

Comment: no it is not, that's is correct representation for double quote inside string literal

Comment: @K Ivanov: oh, yes, I need glasses.